# Afted deployment - folder changes permisions

Tags: nginx, chmod

After deploying the project into /website.com/, the folder permissions get changed automatically. So I have to change it, but it's pretty annoying when you have more sites and deployments. Any ideas why are the permissions changing? 
I am using [deployhq](https://www.deployhq.com/) for deploying.